# Merging two pandas dataframe with column values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, merge

I have a df1 which looks like this

```
  Company  SKU  Sales
1    A      X1   10
2    B      Y1   20
3    C      X1   30
4    D      Y1   40
5    E      X2   50
6    F      Y2   60
```

I have another df2 which only the list of SKU

```
    SKU  
1    X1  
2    Y1
```

I want to merge these 2 dfs into another dataframe and the resulting dataframe should have the SKUs in the df2

```
  Company  SKU  Sales
1    A      X1   10
2    B      Y1   20
3    C      X1   30
4    D      Y1   40
```

I tried Left join but it doesn't seem to be working

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2,how='Left',on='SKU')
```

I will appreciate your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like you aren't trying to 'join' the dfs, but rather to select rows from the first where the SKUs match those in the second.

Try something like this:

```
df1.loc[df1['SKU'].isin(df2.SKU)]
```

See: [Select rows from a DataFrame based on values in a column in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17071871/select-rows-from-a-dataframe-based-on-values-in-a-column-in-pandas)

Comment: Thanks @Neil . This is what I am looking for